# In which years in the prefaces to mathematical books thanks to secretaries for typing text books have disappeared?

Tags: math-history

In which years in the prefaces to mathematical books thanks to secretaries for typing text books have disappeared? Just interesting.
When latex won?

Comment: I don't think turning mathematicians into typists and copy editors was the **purpose** of TeX, I think that was a side effect. I imagine that future improvements in technology will make the task of maintaining the campus buildings and roads so simple that it too can be given to the professors.

Comment: interesting! +1

Comment: Does this suggest that secretaries are uncapable of using LaTeX?

Comment: I have never seen such secretaries

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Everybody is capable of using LaTeX. Before there was LaTeX, technical typing was performed by skilled professionals, being too complicated for mere mathematicians.

Comment: @bof That's why I asked my quetion - rather being surprised. (And I do have renowned math books in my shelves where the "skilled typing" consists of hand-drawing sum and integral symbols into typewriter texts)